# How can docker-machine create an EC2 instance in a private subnet?

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker-compose, docker-machine

I have a bastion host in the public subnet through which I usually access the hosts in the private subnet. When I create a docker machine in the private subnet with the command below, it does not complete.

```
export server_name=tomcat-5

docker-machine create \
  --driver amazonec2 \
  --amazonec2-region us-west-2 \
  --amazonec2-vpc-id vpc-8e5488ea \
  --amazonec2-ami ami-6f69a25f \
  --amazonec2-instance-type m3.medium \
  --amazonec2-zone b \
  --amazonec2-subnet-id subnet-52f5dd54 \
  --amazonec2-security-group tomcat-sg-SecurityGroup-JHHNDKKL4LO1 \
  --amazonec2-tags Name,${server_name} \
  --amazonec2-root-size 10 \
  --amazonec2-ssh-user ec2-user \
  --amazonec2-ssh-keypath ~/.ssh/id_rsa \
  --amazonec2-private-address-only \
  ${server_name}
```

It says

```
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(tomcat-5) Launching instance...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
```

and after that it just hangs for ever. Obviously it does not know how to get to the server via the bastion. And I cannot name the server so that docker can leverage the .ssh/config (if it will do that).

It is hard to imagine that others have not run into it. I ultimately plan to bring up these servers using docker compose. So if I can do that without docker-machine, that is fine too.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get more information about the problem by turning on debug. Essentially

```
docker-machine --debug....
```

This allowed me to see that docker-machine was trying to ssh into an IP with ec2-user@10.x.y.z with these parameters

```
{[-F /dev/null -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 
-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=quiet -o ConnectionAttempts=3 
-o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=none ec2-user@10.x.y.z 
-o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i /Users/jvarg/.docker/machine/machines/tomcat-2/id_rsa 
-p 22] /usr/bin/ssh <nil>}
```

Getting closer. I was able to directly ssh into the machine by updating my ~/.ssh/config by creating a proxy for my subnet. But docker machine is not using that config file. As you can see it use /dev/null. "-F /dev/null".

I looked in the docker machine code and this seems to be hardcoded. https://github.com/docker/machine/blob/df2d3811ca8bc9ddf6896b4a4154b9277826b441/libmachine/ssh/client.go#L69

I have created an issue on the github to follow up. https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/3794

**Update**: While we wait for that PR to be accepted (now stuck with merge conflicts) here is a lame workaround. Login to bastion and use that as an orchestrator instead of your laptop. On the bastion install docker and docker-machine. Also make sure you create a new key-pair there so as not to compromise your own. I did not install ssh agent. So if you go the same way, make sure the key pair has no pass phrase. You will be able to finally ssh into it. But it will then fail with

```
notifying bugsnag: [Error creating machine: Error running provisioning: exit status 1]
```

While it is not obvious from that error, a detailed analysis of the debug output showed that it was failing because the new machine was not able to get out to the internet. This is usually not an issue for most of you. In my company's case we use an http_proxy. But I resolved this by setting up a NAT gateway.

The next error was because the bastion could not communicate on port 2376 with the new machine. Normally docker-machine creates a security group with 2376 open to the world. My company frowns on open-to-the-world ports. So I had updated my SG to allow access from the bastion. But I guess I need to tweak it.

Answer (score 0):

I installed an OpenVPN server on the bastion (actually a NAT gateway). Then my client connects to the OpenVPN server. The OpenVPN server pushes a route allowing the client to access the private subnet work on the VPC.

This works transparently. I can use docker-machine to create nodes on the private network. I can even start docker on my client and join an existing swarm.